# Which Policy is needed for elasticmapreduce:RunJobFlow in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-emr, amazon-data-pipeline

I'm using AWS DataPipeline to run an aws-cli command that creates an EMR Cluster, but I'm getting the following error when the command runs:

```
user ... is not authorized to perform: elasticmapreduce:RunJobFlow
```

I want to associate the right Policy to authorise this, but how do I know which policy is needed?

Answer (score 12):

Select a User > Add Permissions > Attach existing policies directly > AmazonElasticMapReduceFullAccess

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you didn't use the roles that are created by default in your account to run pipelines (DataPipelineDefaultResourceRole and DataPipelineDefaultRole). If this is the case just use that and it should work.